# Ubuntu 23.04 Installation: Failed to start systemd-ud

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, grub-efi

I was trying to install Ubuntu 23.04 on an Intel Core i7 machine, which the installer get stucked on loading screen. Using `F6` button I figured out that it's running a job as below:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start systemd-ud... To Complete Installation
.
.
.
[••••••] job modprobe efi_pstore.service/start running ( x mins and y seconds / no limits)
```

Even running safe graphics didn't help.

Prost!

Comment: After I pressed `alt` key on my keyboard, the screen disappeared and a blinking underline symbol _ showed up and system is dead.

Comment: Please kindly note that when I ran the installer again from USB, it can detect my previous Installation.

Comment: I even tried `gparted` live, to change partitions flags, but didn't worked.

Comment: When I boot the use with Legacy BIOS, it skips that stage but I cannot boot my new installation.